# Switch between UIViewControllers with UISegmentedControl

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios6, navigation, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to switch between 3 views with a UISegmentedControl but I'm stuck.

I'm using storyboards and ARC and I got this so far:

I have dragged the Segmented Control into my VC and then I made an IBOutlet and an IBAction connecting to the segmented control.

This is how the .h file looks like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SCViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segment;

- (IBAction)changeSeg:(id)sender;
@end
```

Then in the .m file:

```
#import "SCViewController.h"

@interface SCViewController ()

@end

@implementation SCViewController

@synthesize segment;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
[self setSegment:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
}

- (IBAction)changeSeg:(id)sender {


if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
    NSLog(@"page one pressed");
    [self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"segmentView1"]];

}
if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
    NSLog(@"page two pressed");
    [self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"segmentView2"]];

}

}
@end
```

The console displays the NSLog message but no views are switched (the vc segmentView1 and segmentView2 exists in the storyboard)

Maybe I'm using a wrong approach in this?

What I want to achieve is the functionality like the iDaft2 app. In there you have 2 or 3 pages and you can switch between them easily.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have added a single view controller, then I drop UIViews in it and use `setHidden` to toggle between them with buttons. I don't think that it's the best solution (should be one better out there) but it does the job.

Views:

```
//  Set views visibility you must make an @property in .h file for each view
//  Like: @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *firstPage;
[_firstPage setHidden:NO];
[_secondPage setHidden:YES];
[_thirdPage setHidden:YES];
```

Toggle button:

```
- (IBAction)switchOne:(id)sender {

[_firstPage setHidden:NO];
[_secondPage setHidden:YES];
[_thirdPage setHidden:YES];
}
```